# Registration in Russia

Tags: visas, russia, moscow, registration

My Russian visit goes like this: I arrived on the evening of the 19th. I am here in Moscow, until Tuesday 26th when I am heading to St. Petersburg. Staying there for four nights, on 29th I am back to Moscow, and travelling back early in the morning of 2nd November.

So, to recap:

19.10 - 26.10: Moscow, which sums up to 6 working days.

26.10 - 29.10: St. Petersburg, sums up to 4 days (staying in the hotel, gonna be registered there).

29.10 - 02.11: back to Moscow, sums up to 3 days if we are counting the Friday.

My host for Moscow apartment (AirBNB) told me they will not be around and I should not be worried about registration anyways. Honestly, this is unsettling and makes me feel super anxious about the situation.

Any experience, advice, anything that might be helpful?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the host explain why you should not be worried about registration anyway? According to the law (I may provide a link, but it's in Russian only), you must register within 7 working days since you arrived in Russia, so if you register at the hotel in St. Petersburg, it should be fine, as far as I understand.

Comment: She claims they never ask for this when you're in Russia on a tourist visa. 
But, this is her claim only after she realized she will not be in Moscow to do the registration. 
If this is the right way to read it, okay, it seems to be okay, but I am not super happy to take this chance.

Comment: Anecdotal, but Benjamin of B&Bankrupt very recently mumbled something about hotels sometimes asking to see some kind of paperwork from your previous accommodation. If that happened then maybe St. Petersburg could be an issue. Though perhaps the Airbnb receipt might do- the hotel would have no way of knowing if they actually registered, I guess.

Comment: I called the host today, insisting we meet if they are in Moscow today. We did the registration. Took around 30 minutes in total, and it was super easy, if that helps anyone here.

Comment: Hotels do not worry about your registration at other hotels. Registration is a formality for the government and courtesy for you. You only need to register if you plan to stay longer than a week. Since you are moving so much, your registration wont matter. I hope that helps.